Matthew 5:23-24 Who does adelphos (ἀδελφός, brother) refer to?

23 Therefore if thou bring thy gift to the altar, and there rememberest that thy brother hath ought against thee; 24 Leave there thy gift before the altar, and go thy way; first be reconciled to thy brother, and then come and offer thy gift. [Matthew 5:23,24 KJV]

As I have been researching this verse, I have come across many different answers to this question. Some believe adelphos(ἀδελφός, brother) applies to many different people who are relationally close to you (believers and nonbelievers) and some say it's only for conflicts with other believers. Can someone help me understand this better?

How would a non-believer be my 'brother' ? ? It is clearly someone who also associates with the altar which I, myself, approach. Otherwise, there would be no conflict.

BDAG lists two principle meanings of the word ἀδελφός (adelphos), "brother":

a male from the same womb as the reference person, brother, eg, Matt 1:2, 11, 4:18, 21, John 1:41, etc
a person viewed as a brother in terms of a close affinity, brother, fellow member, member, associate -


(a) one who shares beliefs... Jesus called everyone who is devoted to him "brother", Matt 12:50, Mark 3:35, especially disciples, Matt 28:10, John 20:17... Hence general for those in spiritual communion, Matt 25:40, Heb 2:12... Hence used by Christians in their relations with one another, Rom 8:29, 1 Cor 5:11, Eph 6:23, 1 Tim 6:2, Acts 6:3, 9:30, 10:23, Rev 1:9, 12:10, etc.
(b) a compatriot, Acts 2:29, 3:17, 22, 7:2, 23, 25, Rom 9:3, etc.
(c) without reference to a common nationality or faith - specifically in the sense of 'neighbor', Matt 5:22ff, 7:3ff, 18:15, 21, 35, Luke 6:41f, 17:3

Thus, the word ἀδελφός appears to be a very broad term covering almost anyone with whom one has any kind of personal (but platonic) relationship.
For the record, BDAG classifies the meaning in the OP's verse of Matt 5:23, 24 as # 2(c) above.  That is, Jesus is instructing His followers (those who hear His words) to resolve all conflict as promptly as practicable.

The term adelphos (ἀδελφός) in Matthew 5:23–24, often translated as "brother," carries a range of meanings in biblical usage, from literal familial relationships to broader spiritual or relational connections. The interpretation of this word in this passage must take into account its usage in other parts of Scripture and the cultural context.

Adelphos in the Septuagint (LXX) and Family Contexts

In the Septuagint, adelphos is used to describe the relationship among the sons of Jacob, even though they were half-brothers from different mothers (e.g., Genesis 37:2–4). This demonstrates that adelphos can denote familial bonds beyond the narrow definition of full siblings.
The word often conveys a sense of shared identity within a familial or covenant community, emphasizing relational proximity.

Implication for Matthew 5:23–24: Here, adelphos could represent anyone within a shared community, such as a fellow Israelite or someone with whom the individual has a significant relational tie.

Adelphos Applied to Jesus' Brothers

In John 7:5, Jesus’ physical brothers (adelphoi) are mentioned as not believing in Him and even mocking Him. This instance shows that adelphos can refer to individuals who are biologically related but not aligned in faith or conduct.
Despite their unbelief and mockery, Jesus continued to engage with them, illustrating that reconciliation and relational integrity extend beyond spiritual unity.

Implication for Matthew 5:23–24: If Jesus' unbelieving brothers were still considered adelphoi, the term in this passage could extend to individuals who are not necessarily believers but have a relational or covenantal connection to the individual.

Cultural and Theological Context of Matthew 5:23–24

Covenantal Framework: In Jewish thought, "brother" often extended to fellow Israelites, as seen in passages such as Deuteronomy 15:12. This covenantal concept likely informed Jesus' audience, implying that adelphos refers to those within the community of Israel.
Reconciliation as a Priority: The focus of Matthew 5:23–24 is the importance of reconciliation before approaching God in worship. This reflects the communal and relational ethos of the Sermon on the Mount, where Jesus emphasizes the heart’s intent over legalistic practices (cf. Matthew 5:21–26).

Implication: The emphasis is less on the faith status of the "brother" and more on the existence of unresolved conflict. Jesus underscores that unresolved grievances with any relationally significant person hinder true worship.


Conclusion
In light of the above points:

Adelphos in Matthew 5:23–24 most likely refers to any relationally significant person, which could include family, fellow believers, or members of one's community.
While the immediate context suggests a covenantal (Jewish) audience, the principle extends to broader human relationships in the spirit of Jesus’ teachings on love and reconciliation (cf. Matthew 5:44).

This interpretation aligns with Jesus' broader message of restoring broken relationships as an act of true righteousness before God.
